# How to insert fa-fa icon to search form

Tags: html, font-awesome

I need a little help with a search form icon. The button tag class `<i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>` doesn't work:

```html
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" onsubmit="check_search();return false;">
  <label>
    <input type="search" class="searchfieldz" placeholder="Search anything " value="" name="s" title="Search for:" autocomplete="off">
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what is going wrong?

Comment: `fa-search` is from FontAwesome. Did you remember to include the `FontAwesome` reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" onsubmit="check_search();return false;">
  <label>
    <input type="search" class="searchfieldz" placeholder="Search anything " value="" name="s" title="Search for:" autocomplete="off">
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

Try to add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```